# Symfony2 choice with static list

Tags: symfony, doctrine, formbuilder

I want to use a select box with predefined values. I have a Task entity:

```
namespace xx\xxx\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * Task
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="xx\xxx\Entity\TaskRepository")
 */
class Task
{

////

/**
 * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"MONTHLY", "WEEKLY"}, message = "Select frequency")
 * @ORM\Column(name="frequency", type="text")
 */
private $frequency;    
}
```

When using TaskType:

```
$builder->add('frequency');
```

shows input, which validates correctly - allows only WEEKLY and MONTHLY values. But I want to use select box. I have tried:

```
   $builder->add('frequency', 'collection', array(
           'type' => 'choice',
           'options' => array(
               'choices' => array(
                   'MONTHLY' => 'Monthly',
                   'WEEKLY' => 'Weekly',
               )
           )
       )
   )
```

or:

```
   $builder->add('frequency', 'collection', array(
           'type' => 'choice',
       )
   )
```

but both ways I only get a label with no select box. What I am doing wrong? Maybe there is better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do it this way:

```
$builder->add('frequency', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => array(
        'MONTHLY'   => 'Monthly',
        'WEEKLY'    => 'Weekly'
    )
));
```

More on `choice` field type here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html